# Iterating through Firebase Database without Google Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

since my goal to create a userlist i need to iterate through Firebase Realtime Database the individual UIDs that are in /users/.
How to accomplish this in Vue3 and Firebase for Web even being able to get the data inside the UIDs for each block i want to display?

Thank.

I tried

```
<script setup>
import { getDatabase, ref as dbref, set, child, get, push } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
import "firebase/database";

    const auth = getAuth();
    const database = getDatabase();
    const dbRef = dbref(getDatabase());
    
    const name = reactive({ value: "" });
    const email = reactive({ value: "" });
    const story = reactive({ value: "" });
    const data5 = reactive({ value: '' });
    
    const target = {
      message1: "",
      message2: "",
    };  
    const handler3 = {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (prop === "message2") {

        get(child(dbRef, 'users/')).then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
        let data4 = (JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
        data5.value = data4
        } else {
        console.log("No data available");
        }
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        });
        }
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
      },
    };
    const proxy3 = new Proxy(target, handler3);
    proxy3.message2;

</script>

<template>{{ data5.value }}
<li v-for="email in data5.value">{{ data5.value }}</li>
</template>
```

It only repeats the whole database with the individual entries in sequence.
Does it work? Else i need to go the steps to activate Cloud Functions and actually pay for the Blaze plan, and learn them. I will do that anyway but i want to also try it first because it is essential to what i try.

It is what i try because everything else seems to fail as a concept.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have data for individual users under `/users` in your database. If that is the case, you can show the data for each user with:

```
get(child(dbRef, 'users/')).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
    console.log(userSnapshot.key);                // show the key of the user node
    console.log(userSnapshot.val());              // show the entire value of the user node
    console.log(userSnapshot.child("uid").val()); // show only property of the user node
  })
});
```